# XE4 ( Firemonkey + iOS Static Library) , Pascal conversion from Objective C Class?

Tags: delphi, class, type-conversion, static-libraries, firemonkey

How to Conversion ? (Objective C Class -> Delphi XE4 )

and How to use Objective-C Class in static Library from Delphi XE ?

Following is the my first trial.
But It makes error.

**Objective C Source**

```
// objective C : test.h ----------------------------------------
@interface objc_test : NSObject {
  BOOL busy;
} 
- (int) test :(int) value;
@end

// objective C : test.m ----------------------------------------
@implementation objc_test
- (int) test :(int) value {
    busy   = true;
    return( value + 1);
 }
@end
```

Here is wrong my conversion code.
How to fix that ?

**Delphi Source**

```
// Delphi XE4 / iOS  -------------------------------------------
{$L test.a} // ObjC Static Library 

type
 objc_test = interface (NSObject)
 function  test(value : integer) : integer; cdecl;
end;

Tobjc_test = class(TOCLocal)
  Public
   function  GetObjectiveCClass : PTypeInfo; override;
   function  test(value : integer): integer; cdecl; 
end;

implmentation  

function  Tobjc_test.GetObjectiveCClass : PTypeInfo;
 begin
  Result := TypeInfo(objc_test);
 end;

function  Tobjc_test.test(value : integer): integer;
 begin
  // ????????
  //
 end;
```

Thanks

Simon,Choi

Comment: You appear to be implementing the function in both obj-c and pascal. Don't you want to implement in obj-c and consume in pascal?

Comment: What's more, I'm sure that the compiler does more than "make error". The compiler makes the effort to describe the error. Why can't you make the effort to tell us what it says?

Answer (score 6):

When you want to import a Objective C class you have to do the following:

```
type
  //here you define the class with it's non static Methods
  objc_test = interface (NSObject)
    [InterfaceGUID]
    function  test(value : integer) : integer; cdecl;     
  end;

type
  //here you define static class Methods 
  objc_testClass = interface(NSObjectClass)
    [InterfaceGUID]
  end;

type
  //the TOCGenericImport maps objC Classes to Delphi Interfaces when you call Create of TObjc_TestClass
  TObjc_TestClass = class(TOCGenericImport<objc_testClass, objc_Test>) end;
```

Also you need a `dlopen('test.a', RTLD_LAZY)` (dlopen is defined in Posix.Dlfcn)

Then you can use the code as following:

```
procedure Test;
var
   testClass: objc_test;
begin
   testClass := TObjc_TestClass.Create;
   testClass.test(3);

end;
```

Comment: Really Really Thanks, Lars.
It is very much helpful glue to start.