# Can Delphi XE4 import iOS ObjC Class ? ( Static Library *.a )

Tags: objective-c, delphi, hyperlink, static-libraries, firemonkey

Can Delphi XE4 import iOS ObjC Class ? ( Static Library *.a )

**ObjC Code  :  test.a**

```
// test.h ---------------------------------------------------------------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface mycalc : NSObject {
   BOOL busy;
  }
- (int) calc : (int) value;
@end


//  test.m --------------------------------------------------------------
#import "test.h"
@implementation mycalc
 -(int) calc:(int)value {
    busy = TRUE;
    return ( value + 1);
  }
@end
```

**Delphi XE4 Code "Unit1.pas" for Testing**

```
Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, 
  System.Variants,System.TypInfo,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  //
  Posix.Dlfcn,
  Macapi.ObjectiveC,Macapi.ObjCRuntime,
  iOSapi.CocoaTypes,iOSapi.foundation,iOSapi.uikit,iOSapi.CoreGraphics;

{$Link libtest.a} // <-- ObjC Static Library (3 Architectures included)
                  //     But Compiled binary size is always same,
                  //     with or without "$Link libtest.a" lines.

type
  //
  mycalc = interface(NSObject)
   ['{12891142-0F45-410D-A9EF-212F1AE23294}'] // Any Unique GUID
   function  test(value : integer) : integer; cdecl; 
  end;

  mycalcclass = interface(NSObjectClass)
   ['{42891142-0F45-410D-A9EF-212F1AE23295}'] // Any Unique GUID
   end;

  //the TOCGenericImport maps objC Classes to Delphi Interfaces 
  // when you call Create of TObjc_TestClass
  TmycalcClass = class(TOCGenericImport<mycalcclass, mycalc>) end;

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 Var
  occalc : mycalc;
  rtn    : integer;
  handle : integer;
begin
 handle := dlOpen('libtest.a',RTLD_LAZY); // ## Q2 : Is It Right ?
 occalc := TmycalcClass.Create;           // ## Q3 : Error :
                                          //          Can't found ObjC Class mycalc  
 rtn := occalc.test(100);                  
 Button1.Text := 'rst:' + IntToStr(rtn);
end;

end.
```

I rewrite the code with **Lars' advice** [XE4 ( Firemonkey + iOS Static Library) , Pascal conversion from Objective C Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515218),
Compiling is OK.

But, After running the program in iPad3 device, When press the button,
It shows **"ObjectiveC class myclac cound not be found"**

My Questions are

Q1.  Is it right syntax for XE4 & iOS Static Library ?

Q2.  with / wihtout Line {$Link libtest.a} 
     Compiled size is same always. What's is wrong in my code ?

Q3.  I know iOS App can't use static library except apple library.
     So, dlOpen is not required. Is it right ?

Always Thanks

Simon, Choi

Comment: I answered it yesterday here on SO

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515218/xe4-firemonkey-ios-static-library-pascal-conversion-from-objective-c-clas/16517527#16517527

Comment: Thanks, Lars. With your help, I write the code like above. compiling is ok, but when button pressed, It show "Can't found ObjC Class myCalc". It seems Code is Ok, But, libtest.a is not loaded. Can you help me what is wrong ? or Can I edit build (link) Option ?

Comment: Did you add the call to 'dlopen' in your code ?

Comment: Yes, Delphi XE4 Code Above, You can see that line when scroll down. But It has same result. I found code size is alway same, with or without {$Link libtest.a} line. even more like {$Link notexists.a} code is compiled. Is It another problem ?

Comment: Could you upload the Libtest.a somewhere? I would like to try it l by myself

Comment: Very Sorry, And Very^100 Thank you :)
Src Code here http://app.pixo.kr/creshot/ex02.zip  It is very important to me, because my app must use the blocks syntax (99.9% Pascal + 0.1% C) But, 0.1% C  code is based function. So If It's not possible, I use the free pascal compiler until xe4's functionality will be prepared. thanks.

Comment: Solved  :) http://blog.naver.com/simonsayz/120190032530

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question. I suggest you do so.