# Can I use Objective C codes with Delphi XE5

Tags: ios, objective-c, delphi, delphi-xe5

I am trying to write an ios program wiht Delphi XE5.
You know there are bunch of ready to use Objective C codes to accomplish a lot of things.
I am just wondering if it is possible to use those Objective C codes under Delphi XE5.
Like we use Assembly codes between code line blocks

```
asm
    // ...
  end;
```

can we say

```
ObjectiveC
My Objective C code
end;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Might be helpful to read [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16548367/960757) or e.g. [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16515218/960757) (and I bet there's more of them).

Comment: `tehcodez { ... } end;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile Delphi compiler compiles Object Pascal only. What you can do is to compile the Obj-C code to object files and link those using $LINK. Or compile the Obj-C into a shared object and consume that.

Comment: Actually it sounds great but little bit complicated. Lets say I have an xcode project which has an objective C function (CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent) which sends virtual keyboard strokes to applications how can I use that function in my DelphiXE5 program

Comment: Build it into a shared object and link to it. Or compile to an object and link that. Or translate to Delphi.

Comment: an example woulb be great :). How can I link, compiled shared object to delphi? just drag the file in project folder and use its compiled name under Uses?

Comment: No. You need to write an import unit. Read the docs. The key is the external keyword. It's just the same as importing a Windows DLL. Loads of examples in the iOS RTL source.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot type the objective-c codes between the pascal codes.

It makes sense. Imagine the mess it will create.