# Is there an interface between delphi and Android NDK?

Tags: android, delphi, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I want to create a C library that calls some NDK functions and access these functions in Delphi. Does anyone know where i can find how to do that? I could not find information about it. Interfacing via Java/JNI seems a big detour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use Objective C codes with Delphi XE5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751747/can-i-use-objective-c-codes-with-delphi-xe5)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, not a dup. "Can I?" vs "How?", ObjC vs C, iOS vs Android... Maybe close to NARQ but not a dup

Comment: I think NDK itself is a set of C libraries, so just look into Delphi RTL sources how it does interface with NDK functions. You would have to make just similar imports for your library, as Embarcadero made for NDK libs.

Comment: @Arioch'The It's all the same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the OP appears to be wanting to use a precompiled (native code) .so (i.e., Linux DLL). As such, the question is hardly a duplicate of someone asking if it's possible to include Objective-C code inside a Pascal unit.

Comment: @Chris That's not how I read the other question. Can Delphi compile Obj-C? Well no. Can Delphi link to Obj-C? Yes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - this question is about linking *to*; the other is about linking *in*

Comment: @ChrisRolliston I'm not sure I understand the difference. I suspect the distinction is not required by either asker. Either asker just wants to be able to execute the code, one way or another.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - linking to a DLL vs. linking in a C object file

Comment: @ChrisRolliston If you would prefer static linking, but dynamic linking is all that the system supports, would you give up, or use dynamic linking?