# Delphi OS X can't load dynamic library - no suitable image found

Tags: macos, delphi

I've create a delphi project and Objective C dynamic library according to [XE4 ( Firemonkey + iOS Static Library) , Pascal conversion from Objective C Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515218/xe4-firemonkey-ios-static-library-pascal-conversion-from-objective-c-clas/16517527#16517527) but to run on OS X.

But the dylib won't load from the delphi project, checking the error for the load with:

```
handle := dlopen('/<path>/libtest2.dylib', RTLD_LAZY);
  if (handle=0) then
  begin
    p := dlerror();
    SetString(s, p, StrLen(p));
    ShowMessage('failed to load lib: ' + s)
  end
```

Now the error I get says

```
failed to load lib: dlopen(/<path>/libtest2.dylib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /<path>/libtest2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Some googling around and I find I should check the architecture with lip, and I get architecture x86_64 when run against the dylib as it should be, but when I run it against the delphi project I get

```
lipo -info /<path>/Project4.app
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't map input file: /<path>/Project4.app (Invalid argument)
```

not sure if this is the root of my problem but running out of ideas - any suggestions? Maybe I should be doing something else to load a dynamic library in OS X?

(Delphi XE6 update 1 OSX 10.10)

Update: the actual delphi binary is contained with in the app file and digging into it it is i386, so thats the problem. Now have to figure out how to generate an i386 dylib.

Update 2: Well it's because Delphi makes 32 bit binaries and the objective c dylib is 64 bit, and it can't be 32 bit. So how does Delphi interface with the OS X frameworks? There is a way, does any one know how to do it?

Update 3: to make a 32 bit dylib turn off ARC, i.e. set 'Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting' to no in build settings and we're away. Hopefully 64 bit support will be in the next release of Delphi - a reason to upgrade.

tia

Comment: If you want OSX-64, make sure you vote for https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11297 Emailing Marco Cantu or Jim McKeeth to let them know what you need and why may also help. I'm sure it is coming "sometime" but things like that help make it sooner rather than later :) Let them know you'll upgrade, too - money talks, you know how it is.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @DavidM - voted, and I'll send off an email, I was wanting to get into metal next year and I suspect it won't have a 32 bit interface. I was freaking out for a bit when I thought I couldn't access things from Xcode :-), but there's always a way.